# How to use an Actor based source with an Akka Graph?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-cluster

I'm attempting to send data via an actor to a runnable graph that contains a fan out.

I define the source as :

```
final Source<Integer, ActorRef> integerSource =
        Source.actorRef(
                elem -> {
                    if (elem == Done.done()) return Optional.of(CompletionStrategy.immediately());
                    else return Optional.empty();
                },
                elem -> Optional.empty(),
                10,
                OverflowStrategy.dropHead());
```

But I'm unsure how to get a handle on an `ActoRef` to send data via an actor to the source so that the runnable graph will process messages asynchronously as they are received :

```
RunnableGraph<CompletionStage<Done>> graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(
        GraphDSL.create(sink, (builder, out) -> {
            SourceShape<Integer> sourceShape = builder.add(integerSource);
            FlowShape<Integer, Integer> flow1Shape = builder.add(flow1);
            FlowShape<Integer, Integer> flow2Shape = builder.add(flow1);
            UniformFanOutShape<Integer, Integer> broadcast =
                    builder.add(Broadcast.create(2));
            UniformFanInShape<Integer, Integer> merge =
                    builder.add(Merge.create(2));

            builder.from(sourceShape)
                    .viaFanOut(broadcast)
                    .via(flow1Shape);

            builder.from(broadcast).via(flow2Shape);

            builder.from(flow1Shape)
                    .viaFanIn(merge)
                    .to(out);

            builder.from(flow2Shape).viaFanIn(merge);


            return ClosedShape.getInstance();
        } )
);
```

Entire src :

```
import akka.Done;
import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.Behaviors;
import akka.stream.*;
import akka.stream.javadsl.*;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

@Slf4j
public class GraphActorSource {

    private final static ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create(Behaviors.empty(), "flowActorSystem");

    public void runFlow() {


        final Source<Integer, ActorRef> integerSource =
                Source.actorRef(
                        elem -> {
                            if (elem == Done.done()) return Optional.of(CompletionStrategy.immediately());
                            else return Optional.empty();
                        },
                        elem -> Optional.empty(),
                        10,
                        OverflowStrategy.dropHead());


        Flow<Integer, Integer, NotUsed> flow1 = Flow.of(Integer.class)
                .map (x -> {
                    System.out.println("Flow 1 is processing " + x);
                    return (x * 2);
                });

        Sink<Integer, CompletionStage<Done>> sink = Sink.foreach(x -> {
            System.out.println(x);
        });

        RunnableGraph<CompletionStage<Done>> graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(
                GraphDSL.create(sink, (builder, out) -> {
                    SourceShape<Integer> sourceShape = builder.add(integerSource);
                    FlowShape<Integer, Integer> flow1Shape = builder.add(flow1);
                    FlowShape<Integer, Integer> flow2Shape = builder.add(flow1);
                    UniformFanOutShape<Integer, Integer> broadcast =
                            builder.add(Broadcast.create(2));
                    UniformFanInShape<Integer, Integer> merge =
                            builder.add(Merge.create(2));

                    builder.from(sourceShape)
                            .viaFanOut(broadcast)
                            .via(flow1Shape);

                    builder.from(broadcast).via(flow2Shape);

                    builder.from(flow1Shape)
                            .viaFanIn(merge)
                            .to(out);

                    builder.from(flow2Shape).viaFanIn(merge);


                    return ClosedShape.getInstance();
                } )
        );

        graph.run(actorSystem);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new GraphActorSource().runFlow();
    }
}
```

How to send data to the Runnable graph via an actor?

Something like ? :

```
integerSource.tell(1)
integerSource.tell(2)
integerSource.tell(3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActorRef.tell` works.  Construct the graph blueprint so the source `ActorRef` will be returned when the blueprint is materialized and run.

For just one materialized object, use that materialized type for the materialized type parameter of the `Graph`.

Here the materialized type parameter for `integerSource` is `ActorRef`.
The materialized type parameter for `Graph` is also `ActorRef`.
Only `integerSource` is passed to `GraphDSL.create`.

```
Source<Integer, ActorRef> integerSource = ...

Graph<ClosedShape, ActorRef> graph =
  GraphDSL.create(integerSource, (builder, src) -> {
     ...
  });

RunnableGraph<ActorRef> runnableGraph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(graph);

ActorRef actorRef = runnableGraph.run(actorSystem);

actorRef.tell(1, ActorRef.noSender());
```

To access more than one materialized object, a tuple must be constructed to capture them.  If two objects from the materialized graph are desired, say src and snk, then `Pair<A,B>` can capture both types.

Here both `integersource` and `sink` are passed to `GraphDSL.create`.
The materialized `ActorRef` and `CompletionStage` are paired for the result of `run` with `Pair::new`.
The type `Pair<ActorRef,CompletionStage<Done>>` is the materialized type parameter of the `Graph`.

```
Source<Integer, ActorRef> integerSource = ...
Sink<Integer, CompletionStage<Done>> sink = ...

Graph<ClosedShape, Pair<ActorRef, CompletionStage<Done>>> graph =
      GraphDSL.create(integerSource, sink, Pair::new, (builder, src, snk) -> {
....
});

RunnableGraph<Pair<ActorRef, CompletionStage<Done>>> runnableGraph =
  RunnableGraph.fromGraph(graph);

Pair<ActorRef, CompletionStage<Done>> pair =
  runnableGraph.run(actorSystem);
ActorRef actorRef = pair.first();
CompletionStage<Done> completionStage = pair.second();

actorRef.tell(1, ActorRef.noSender());
```

Full example:

(build.gradle)

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "application"
mainClassName = "GraphActorSource"
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies { 
  implementation "com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor-typed_2.13:2.6.19"
  implementation "com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-typed_2.13:2.6.19"
  implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.36'
}
compileJava {
  options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
}
```

(src/main/java/GraphActorSource.java)

```
import akka.Done;
import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.Status.Success;
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.Behaviors;
import akka.japi.Pair;
import akka.stream.*;
import akka.stream.javadsl.*;
import akka.util.Timeout;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class GraphActorSource {

  private final static ActorSystem actorSystem =
    ActorSystem.create(Behaviors.empty(), "flowActorSystem");

  public void runFlow() {

    // 1. Create graph (blueprint)

    // 1a. Define source, flows, and sink

    final Source<Integer, ActorRef> integerSource =
      Source.actorRef
      (
        elem -> {
          if (elem == Done.done()) return Optional.of(CompletionStrategy.immediately());
          else return Optional.empty();
        },
        elem -> Optional.empty(),
        10,
        OverflowStrategy.dropHead()
      );


    Flow<Integer, Integer, NotUsed> flow1 = Flow.of(Integer.class)
      .map (x -> {
          System.out.println("Flow 1 is processing " + x);
          return (100 + x);
        });
    Flow<Integer, Integer, NotUsed> flow2 = Flow.of(Integer.class)
      .map (x -> {
          System.out.println("Flow 2 is processing " + x);
          return (200 + x);
        });

    Sink<Integer, CompletionStage<Done>> sink = Sink.foreach(x -> {
        System.out.println("Sink received "+x);
      });

    // 1b. Connect nodes and flows into a graph.
    // Inputs and output nodes (source, sink) will be produced at run start.

    Graph<ClosedShape, Pair<ActorRef, CompletionStage<Done>>> graph =
      GraphDSL.create(integerSource, sink, Pair::new, (builder, src, snk) -> {
          UniformFanOutShape<Integer, Integer> broadcast =
          builder.add(Broadcast.create(2));
          FlowShape<Integer, Integer> flow1Shape = builder.add(flow1);
          FlowShape<Integer, Integer> flow2Shape = builder.add(flow2);
          UniformFanInShape<Integer, Integer> merge =
          builder.add(Merge.create(2));

          builder.from(src)
          .viaFanOut(broadcast);

          builder.from(broadcast.out(0))
          .via(flow1Shape)
          .toInlet(merge.in(0));

          builder.from(broadcast.out(1))
          .via(flow2Shape)
          .toInlet(merge.in(1));

          builder.from(merge)
          .to(snk);

          return ClosedShape.getInstance();
        } );

    RunnableGraph<Pair<ActorRef, CompletionStage<Done>>> runnableGraph =
      RunnableGraph.fromGraph(graph);

    // 2. Start run,
    // which produces materialized source ActorRef and sink CompletionStage.

    Pair<ActorRef, CompletionStage<Done>> pair =
      runnableGraph.run(actorSystem);
    ActorRef actorRef = pair.first();
    CompletionStage<Done> completionStage = pair.second();

    // On completion, terminates actor system (optional).
    completionStage.thenRun(() -> {
        System.out.println("Done, terminating.");
        actorSystem.terminate();
      });
          
    // 3. Send messages to source actor

    actorRef.tell(1, ActorRef.noSender());
    actorRef.tell(2, ActorRef.noSender());

    // The stream completes successfully with the following message
    actorRef.tell(Done.done(), ActorRef.noSender());

  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    new GraphActorSource().runFlow();
  }
}
```

Reference Akka Documentation (accessed Version 2.6.19)

[Streams / Operators / Source.actorRef](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/actorRef.html#source-actorref)

[Streams / Streams Cookbook / Working with operators](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-cookbook.html#working-with-operators)